# Why doesn't my hyperlink work when a hashtag is added at the end?

Tags: html, hyperlink

When I generate a hyperlink using simple PHP, I add a # to the end so the page will reload itself and go to a specific ID on the page. But when I do that, it doesn't reload the page with the new info, it just goes down to the id specified in the #. If I remove the #, then the page reloads fine with the new info, but doesn't scroll down to the correct ID.  Here is the code:

```
   <a href='{$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']}?m=$next#oc' title='next month'>&raquo;</a>
```

So as-as, this code won't reload the page. But if I remove the #oc from the hyperlink, it DOES reload the page. What gives? I've tried this on Firefox and Chrome.

I've tried remove the #oc, and the code works but doesn't scroll down to the id="oc" area of the script. I verified that there is only one id="oc" on the page. I've tried re-writing with %23 instead of the # mark, and it reloads the page but doesn't scroll to the correct area.

Comment: The part after the '#' (oc in your case) is called a URI fragment. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_fragment. That article states that "Clients are not supposed to send URI fragments to servers".

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest adding a JS function to reload the page. This is an intentional feature so you can jump to different locations on the page without it constantly reloading and using server bandwidth.

```html
 <a href='{$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']}?m=$next#oc' onclick="reloadPageFunction()" title='next month'>&raquo;</a>
```

edit:

```js
reloadPageFunction() {
location.reload(); 
}
```